# Definition of Haar orthogonal matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, statistics, random-matrices

I recently came across the terminology "Haar orthogonal matrices" in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2112.04330.pdf) (page 4), where they stated that it is the matrix that comes out from singular value decomposition. However, I am not able to decipher what it means (despite knowing what orthogonal matrices are). I have tried searching around google and Wikipedia but to no avail. May I know what it means precisely? Thanks.

Comment: Haar seems to be a reference to the [Haar measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure) over the set of orthogonal matrices. It seems that there is some sense here in which the orthogonal matrices are random. If that is the case, then the "Haar" descriptor is essentially telling you that the distribution over the set of orthogonal matrices is uniform.

Comment: Yes, it must be the unique probability measure on O(n) (n ≠ 4) that is both left and right invariant. For n = 4 there is a 1-dimensional set of such bi-invariant metrics, although there is just one of them that one may consider "nicest".